# Instantiating Objects at Different Intervals Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am trying to make a 3D jumping game where my character is standing still and the objects and background are moving towards him to make it seem like he is running. I have a bunch of models for buildings that I am instantiating using an empty game object that I use as a spawner. I want the buildings to spawn one after each other, so whenever one building has moved far enough and left enough space the next one should spawn. I first tried to do this with InvokeRepeating, but the buildings are different widths so it does not work well with a constant repeat rate. I then tried to put a collider on my spawner and spawn a building whenever the spawner collider is not colliding with anything, but it seems to just spawn buildings infinitely. Is there a way to fix this or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of doing this.

The most straightforward is possibly to let each building spawn the next one, as I assume they each know how wide they are and thus when it's time for the next.

Answer (score 0):

Well , first things first your problem is looking more like a design problem. I would recommend searching things like "procedural world building" , also object pooling. There is lots of examples of runner games that do what you describe.

You can check the palyer position to instantiate , you can create parts of the road as prefabs , make lots and lots of prefabs and instantiate them as you go etc. The question you asked is simply too wide to give an actual answer. So if you have any more spesific questions , it'll be nice to answer !